# "onUpgrade()" method from SQLiteOpenHelper is call on fresh app installed

Tags: android

onUpgrade method is call on fresh app installed, 
When I run my code from Android Studio to my mobile phone, Its working fine ("onCreate" method is called and my Database created successfully) but when I created sign APK(release app) and then I run that app on Phone, its call onUpgrade method and get crashed (Its call Alter Table SQL query which is written), Any help, will be appreciated.

Comment: we don´t know about what you are talking. Please refer:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Show your related code and the logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disable backup by adding following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
  ...
/>
```